# Postgresql Update big table slowly (16 million rows)

Tags: performance, postgresql, rows, updates

I have a big table including around 16 million rows:
POST table:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|             Column             |            Type             | Modifiers |
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| key                            | character varying(36)       | not null  |
| category_id                    | integer                     |           |
| owner_id                       | integer                     |           |
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+
```

key's value contains 36 random characters.

```
INDEXES: btree(key), btree(owner_id), btree(category_id)
```

My GOAL is adding is_deleted attribute to this table, updating owner_id(previously is None) from another table. (around 2 million rows affected)

I tried updating multiple rows with format:

```
update post_tbl as p 
set owner_id = c.owner_id, 
is_deleted = True
from (values
    (92485, 137736), 
    (948130, 250745), 
    (423832, 1164883), 
    (685966, 521767),
    ...
) as c(owner_id, id)
where p.key in c.id;
```

WITH number_of_rows are 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000. However, it seems really slow ~ around 10 rows per second.
So that with 2000000 rows, it might take roughly 50 hours.

I also tried to change postgresql variables:

```
synchronous_commit=off;
wal_buffers=32;
shared_buffers=1GB;
random_page_cost=0.005;
seq_page_cost=0.005;
```

But not much change. (plus I tried to delete btree index in owner_id but nothing changes)

Could you please tell me how can I speed up this update? Thanks.

Comment: How many rows (as a percentage of all rows) satisfy the condition `is_deleted = true`? If that is only a small amount of the rows in the table, an index on `post_tbl(is_deleted, key)` might help

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name around 2/16 = 12.5% rows will be updated. is_deleted=True is in SET command. I have another table called deleted_post, which is used to update back to table post_tbl.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misread that. Could you add the condition `where is_deleted = false` (together with an index on `is_deleted`) or does the list of keys also include rows with `is_deleted = true`?

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN` for the `UPDATE`, and if possible `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for a subset of it.

Comment: With the query is above, the plan is here: http://explain.depesz.com/s/c7z

Comment: Do you have triggers on the table, or referential integrity constraints on it?  What version are you running?  Can you do `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: Thank you guys, I gotta turn off the database (at midnight) in order to do the update. The script ran for hours but luckily we have no problem at all.